# Setting up HSTS Header doesn´t work on FCGI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, owncloud

Hello im working on shared hosting enviroment using PHP 5.6.2 with FastCGI

Some Header settings do work:

```
  <IfModule mod_env.c>
# Add security and privacy related headers 
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Robots-Tag "none"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-Download-Options "noopen"
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
SetEnv modHeadersAvailable true</IfModule>
```

but every try to get the HSTS Header to work is failing so far:

```
 Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```

i hope anyone gets the right hint for me

Comment: Define what you mean by _failing_?

Comment: owncloud is still saying i should activate it and ssllabs.com  is also not showing it is working